# C#, Using self as a parameter for an abstract override method of the base class

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract

How would I override DerivedZ() in the child, without having to specify a U in the base class? The latter solution appears a bit excessive.

```
public abstract class Z {}
public class DerivedZ : Z 
{
    public DerivedZ (B someB, int num)
    {
        // initialize here
    }
}

// will not compile
// error: 'B.GetZ(B, int)': no suitable method found to override
// error: 'B' does not implement inherited abstract member 'A<DerivedZ>.GetZ(A<DerivedZ>, int)'
public abstract class A<T> where T : Z
{
    public abstract T GetZ (A<T> inputA, int optional=1);
}

public class B : A<DerivedZ>
{       
    public override DerivedZ GetZ (B someB, int optional=1)
    {
        return new DerivedZ (someB, optional)
    }
}
```

this works though...

```
public abstract class A<T,U> where T : Z where U : A<T,U>
{
    public abstract T GetZ (U inputA, int optional=1);
}

public class B : A<DerivedZ,B>
{
    public override DerivedZ GetZ (B someB, int optional=1)
    {
        return new DerivedZ (someB, optional);
    }
}
```

Comment: You've showed exactly how this needs to be done.  And the error messages (that you didn't bother to list) make it pretty clear as to why your first solution doesn't work.

Comment: Simple answer: you can't.

Comment: Does `DerivedZ` *need* to accept a `B`, and not an `A<DerivedZ>`?  Does `GetZ` in `B` *need* to accept a `B` and not an `A<DerivedZ>`?

Comment: Just as a little side FYI, the term for your 2nd form that works is called the "[Curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)".

Comment: thanks, I updated it with the error code. Servy, A<DerivedZ> didn't compile either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use the first form, because it's not properly overriding the method. If you *could* do that, imagine this code:

```
public class C : A<DerivedZ> {}

A<DerivedZ> x = new B();
x.GetZ(new C());
```

That should work fine, after all - `A<T>.GetZ` is just declared to accept an `A<T>`, and `C` *is* a `A<DerivedZ>`.

The approach you've shown is fine.

I agree that sometimes it would be useful to be able to say "something of the same type" but it's not part of the C# type system.

Comment: Thanks again for the confirmation Jon, while I have your attention I thought I might ask if you could write a short blog post on designing for composition over inheritance, much appreciative if you do ;)

Comment: Well I wrote this post just over 6 years ago: https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2006/03/04/inheritancetax.aspx I could probably express myself better now though :)

Comment: I'm sure much of it is still relevant, Cheers!